# It really bugs me if

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, word-order

Suppose I have gone to the movies(cinema). There is a man behind me that cracks sun-flower seeds open, talks with the next person, and also talks on his cell phone. I want to say that these behaviors are annoying when I am watching a film in the theater. If I say, "*When I am in the theater, **it really bugs me** if somebody behind me starts cracking seeds, talking with somebody, or answering his phone*,” does this convey what I mean to say?

Is "to bug" a proper usage here?

Is to crack seeds open a proper usage here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes.  Modern synonym for *irk*. Also, I don't know what "cracking seeds" means unless it's literal, but I'm American.  But I guess that means that if *bug* is an American colloquialism(?), try not to blend it with whatever *cracking seeds* is, if not literal.

Comment: I edited my question @stevesliva!, any idea now?:)

Comment: Chewing popcorn... so yeah, literal.  *Bugs* is entirely perfect to my ears.  I don't know if *bothers* is more appropriate elsewhere.

Comment: not popcorn!, but seeds like the ones in the  upper picture @stevesliva! :)

Comment: Better than spitting them.

Comment: do you mean that you "spit the seeds' is the correct phrase? @stevesliva?

Comment: No, sorry. I just mean that the sounds of eating are in general irksome, and that spitting out the shells is probably more even more grating to others than cracking them.   The only reason I went down this tangent of whether "cracking seeds" was literal is because there's "cracking jokes."

Comment: so if  you want to open seasoned pumpkin seeds with yours teeth, how do you say ? I am ....pumpkin seeds now while watching TV. @stevesliva ?:)

Comment: Perhaps "splitting," but cracking is fine, too.

Comment: thanks a lot! dear @stevesliva! :), so do you think that my sentence sound natural, now?

Comment: Yes.  I was more flummoxed by the idea of seeds in theaters than anything else.  *bugs*, as the answer says, is entirely appropriate.

Comment: In neither the US, the UK or in Italy do cinemas (AmEng *theatres*) sell pumpkin seeds to the public/movie goers. It's always been popcorn the traditional cinema snack food, less so in Italy. Is popcorn not sold in your country?

Comment: Yes, @Mari-Luo A!, popcorn and some other snacks are sold in our movie theaters, too. But seasoned pumpkin or sun-flower seeds are among famous and traditional snacks of Iranians, most people cracks them in their family gatherings or when they are watching TV especially important football (soccer) matches. ,( because seed cracking removes some of their stresses!)  , however; cracking seeds in cinemas produces more trashes and is considered more annoying, so it has been forbidden since many years ago. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The verb *[bug](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bug)* fits well with your emotional reaction:

> 2 informal Annoy or bother (someone):
>   <sub>*ODO*</sub>

Imagine how you feel if a swarm of gnats gathers around your head, and starts crawling in your ears, eyes, nose and mouth. The *[bugs](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bug&allowed_in_frame=0)* are *bugging* you in much the same way that man is bugging you with his irritating distractions while you are trying to watch the movie. You can swat the gnats with impunity, but you will need to be a little more gracious to your rude theater-mate.

*[Pester](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pester)* would be another verb to describe his behavior.

---

*[Crack](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/crack)*:

> 1.1 Break or cause to break open or apart:
>   <sub>*ODO*</sub>

*[Crack open](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/crack+open)*:

> [for something brittle] to break or split open.
>   *The egg cracked open and a chick worked its way out.*
>   <sub>*McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.*</sub>

Comment: +1 thanks @ScotM !, What about "to crack seeds"?

Comment: Both are acceptable.

Comment: I prefer "crack" with seeds. You crack nuts, which are seeds. It's also more _ onomatopoeic_ than "split" in this case (and more "buggy", too).

Comment: thanks for your comment, dear @Margana!, yes, I agree with you.:)

Comment: @Margana  Agreed, *crack* sounds definitely louder and more annoying too, "crunching seeds", the sound you make while chewing on them, could also work